# Search user controls within Wpf Project Directory and Reference them as objects

Tags: wpf, list, loops, types, user-controls

Ok so this might be a really really dumb question, Basically what I am trying to do is dynamically add all of the usercontrols in my Project to a `List<UserControl>`

So say in my IDE I've created 2 user controls named *view1.xaml* and *view2.xaml*, and inside a method named **GetAllViews()** I want to look for any files in my project starting with the word *view* (or better yet containing **view*.xaml**) and add them to the `List<UserControl>`.

```
public List<UserControl> viewList = new List<UserControl>();

public void GetAllViews()
        {
            view1 v1 = new view1();
            view2 v2 = new view2();
            viewList.Add(v1);
            viewList.Add(v2);
        }
```

So I basically want to avoid creating a giant visible list of user controls and instantiating them, then adding them to the list one by one, when I could just loop through and and instantiate them from the found controls then add them to the list, make sense?

Maybe I'm thinking about it the wrong way in which case, any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
Adding more code for better context...

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs I'm calling the **GetAllViews()** method to populate the list

```
#region MEMBER VARIABLES

        UtilityFactory uf = new UtilityFactory();
        int _currentView = 0;
        int _previousView = 0;

        #endregion


    #region PROPERTIES

    List<UserControl> ViewList
    {
        get
        {
            return uf.viewList;
        }
    }

    #endregion

public MainWindow()
    {         
        InitializeComponent();
        softRendering();
        uf.GetAllViews();            
        pageTransition.ShowPage(ViewList[_currentView]);
    }
```

Then in btnNext_Click

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (_currentView < ViewList.Count - 1)
        {
            _previousView = _currentView;
            _currentView += 1;
            pageTransition.ShowPage(ViewList[_currentView]);
        }                                                     
    }
```

And basically the opposite for btnBack_click

```
  private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_currentView != 0)
        {
            _currentView = _previousView;
            _previousView += 1;
            pageTransition.ShowPageFromLeft(ViewList[_currentView]);
        }

    }
```

**So Essentially this is what I'm looking to do:**

```
public void GetAllViews2()
        {
            foreach (var uControls in uControlList)
            {
                uControls newControl = uControls();
                viewList.Add(newControl);
            }
        }
```

Comment: A UserControl is nothing but a class. Why do you want to add instances of UserControls to a list? How are you indending to use this list? There is no concept of XAML "files" at runtime. Your XAML files get compiled into resources.

Comment: right, but how could I create an object (class object) from the list of files (classes) I've found? I'm using the list to switch between pages in the Window. So if a user clicks a "next" button I can reference the index of the list to go to the next page or viceversa with a "back" button. From what I can tell I need to have indices to achieve this if I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: You can't add a UserControl to a list without instantiating the UC first so I am not sure if I understand the purpose of what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I want to find all UserControls that I've created, then dynamically instatiate them and add them to the list in the same loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to look for any files in my project starting with the word view (or better yet containing view*.xaml) and add them to the List.

XAML files are compiled into BAML resources when you build your application. The following method should get you a List<UserControl> of all UserControls named "view*.xaml" that are located in the root folder of your project:

```
private List<UserControl> GetUserControls()
{
    List<UserControl> userControls = new List<UserControl>();
    System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    string resourceName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
    using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    using (var reader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(stream))
    {
        foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in reader)
        {
            string key = entry.Key.ToString();
            if (key.StartsWith("view") && key.EndsWith(".baml"))
            {
                System.IO.Stream bamlStream = entry.Value as System.IO.Stream;
                if (bamlStream != null)
                {
                    using (System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader bamlReader = new System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader(bamlStream))
                    {
                        userControls.Add(System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(bamlReader) as UserControl);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return userControls;
    }
}
```

But since UserControl are nothing but classes you should know the name of all your UserControls at compile-time and just be able to create the list "manually" yourself, e.g.:

```
List<UserControl> ucs = new List<UserControl>();
ucs.Add(new view1());
ucs.Add(new view2());
...
```

The results would be the same and the latter approach would be a much better solution in my opinion. It's both easier and faster and less error-prone. But I guess you have your reasons for doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Holy crap, well done sir.  Well I definitely learned something new today. I was thinking there would have to read the entry and convert it to the type that I need. You nailed it right on the head. I do agree the simpler approach is probably the right one. My reasoning is simply that if I add another view.xaml class to the project I wouldn't have to type more code to add it to the list `ucs.Add(new view3());` etc... for example. Probably a stupid reasoning but something I was curious about. Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: Adding another "Add" line is less effort than adding the new UserControl itself :)

Comment: Well not really, since I have to create a user control anyways and save it with a name.... **view3.xaml** then I'm done... don't be a debbie downer